# How to have multiple build configuration for build.yaml file

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, jsonserializer, build-runner

In `json_serializable` package we can define a `build.yaml` file to configure diffrent options. I have 2 folder for my models, one folder is for requests and the other is for responses.
I want to know how to create `build.yaml` with diffrent configuration for both of this folder?
I tried something like this but did not succeed.

```
targets:
  api_package_name:
    builders:
      json_serializable|request:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - "lib/src/models/request/*.dart"
        options:
          include_if_null: false
          checked: true
          create_factory: false
          explicit_to_json: true
          field_rename: snake
      json_serializable|response:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - "lib/src/models/response/*.dart"
        options:
          checked: true
          create_to_json: false
          field_rename: snake
```